# Qt 5.1.0 has supported static compile ? How to?

Tags: qt

From wiki we know 
“Support for static Qt builds making it possible to address those use cases that cannot use dynamic linking”

I have tired adding CONFIG += static , but not gonna work .

How to compile code staticaly without compile the whole qt project ?

---

before Qt5.1.0 we all can compile the code statically after build the qt project

but this time ,qt 5.1.0 wiki said new features include “Support for static Qt”

Answer (score 4):

You need to do a static build of Qt before you can build statically linked applications with it. You have to specify `-static` when you configure it prior to building. None of the existing pre-built packages supports static linking out of the box.

Keep in mind there is a restriction - you cannot use static linking in commercial applications unless you have a commercial license. But it is ok for testing purposes and open source stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this was always possible with Qt?!